# Java validation by xsd with xmlns

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd

me need validate XML by XSD. If i use xsd with no namespace validate is good. But if XSD have targetNamespace i get error.

**Text error : cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'RequestGKN'.**

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<RequestGKN 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns="urn://x-artefacts-rosreestr-gov-ru/requests/gkn/3.0.9">   
    <title>123</title>
</RequestGKN>
```

XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        targetNamespace="urn://x-artefacts-rosreestr-gov-ru/requests/gkn/3.0.9"
        elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="RequestGKN">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>root element</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Title" type="xs:string">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>info</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Java code

```
    Schema schema = null;
    Document document = null;

    xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"  encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>\n" +
            "<RequestGKN xmlns:xs=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns=\"urn://x-artefacts-rosreestr-gov-ru/requests/gkn/3.0.9\">" +
            "<title>123</title>" +
            "</RequestGKN>";
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        builderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder parser = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
        SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        path = locationXSD.substring(0, locationXSD.lastIndexOf('/')+1);

        //factory.setResourceResolver(new ResourceResolver());
        Source schemaFile = new StreamSource(TemplateHandler.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(locationXSD));
        schema = factory.newSchema(schemaFile);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
    validator.validate(new DOMSource(document));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before creating `DocumentBuilder`, make sure the `schema` is set in `DocumentBuilderFactory`.
The `schema` object is thread safe which can be reused without problem.

```
SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
String path = locationXSD.substring(0, locationXSD.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
Source schemaFile = new StreamSource(TemplateHandler.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(locationXSD));
schema = factory.newSchema(schemaFile);//thread safe object which can be reused

DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
builderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
builderFactory.setSchema(schema);
DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));

Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
validator.validate(new DOMSource(document));
```